# android app with database?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android app with a lot of text for item.

For example:

```
-Item A,description: a lot of words...
-Item B,description: A lot of words...
```

What is the best practice to do?? Save that text in a database? And if a have 1000 words? Its good practice to do it? I searched in other applications that have the same context but did not find the folder database...So,I am confused..

If the answer is yes,what is the best practice for create the database? Insert `onCreate()` activity or create the database in third application and put in the app's folder?

Any help will be completely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to save your data in android :

1. Using Shared Preferences which save data using (Key,Value) pair which also used to save small amount of data.
2. Saving data into txt or xml file.
3. And finally save data into Sqllite Database.

you can go through the following links for more details about that [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

And for your case I suggest you go with saving the data into database and you can do so by start reading this tutorial [click here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html), [and this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html), [and this](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/use-of-sqlite/).

Hope this help.

Comment: Ty for your help,but iknow that already :). Anyway im doing something like this https://lh4.ggpht.com/y816WZa-NjprNmIb69NpcPkG7lez-3tHCNNhx4pGVtNJjUj29M7s9HALmrKIx6jVoCY  .So equation and refrence will be in one field in database?

Comment: reference , equation , and the description each one of them should be in separate field to maintain the performance.

Comment: ye ty,thats what i thought